# NoMethodError in pry-stack_explorer when using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry, pry-rails

I am using pry for `rails console`.

Whenever I evaluate some value in console, `NoMethodError` is raised in `bindings_equal?`,  that is a method of `pry-stack_explorer` gem. The input and output is as follows.

That is not harmful but a nuisance. I want to remove it.

Can anyone help?

```
> bundle exec rails console

Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)

Frame number: 0/21
[1] pry(main)> 
[2] pry(main)> 
[3] pry(main)> 1
when_started hook failed: NoMethodError: private method `eval' called for nil:NilClass
{My Bundle Directory}/ruby/2.1.0/gems/pry-stack_explorer-0.4.9.1/lib/pry-stack_explorer.rb:109:in `bindings_equal?'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
=> 1
[4] pry(main)>
```

I use these gems relating to pry:

```
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-remote'
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seeing this same issue without using awesome print, so the below answers don't really help in my case.  Not sure if in your context awesome print is present or not.

Comment: When I had this problem, I was using awesome print and had `~/.pryrc` with `Pry.config.print`. In my case the problem occured by the interference of pry and awesome print. So I can not explain your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not running the same gems as you, but have run across the same error.

I [started an issue](https://github.com/pry/pry-stack_explorer/issues/20) on the github project

Comment: My problem is caused by the same reason. Removing `Pry.config.print` from my `.pryrc` turns the errors off.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to [awesome_print's readme](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print#pry-integration), in order to integrate pry with awesome_print, now we should use `AwesomePrint.pry!` not `Pry.config.print`

Answer (score 3):

I had to add

```
require 'awesome_print'
AwesomePrint.pry!
```

to my `~/.pryrc` (per the [AwesomePrint docs](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print#pry-integration)) to fix this error.

Some are mentioning removing `Pry.config.print` from their `~/.pryrc` but I didn't even have a `~/.pryrc`, so it appears this can happen by just using `awesome_print` and `pry` together.